# How do I implement this JSFiddle example in html and .js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The JSFiddle example in question is http://jsfiddle.net/3vPgY/10/

I copied and pasted the HTML portion into my html file and the two select boxes show up.

```
<form>
<select id="refine">
    <option class="default" value="0">Please refine...</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
<select id="everything" disabled="disabled">
    <option class="default" value="">Please select</option>
    <option class="green" value="green-sel">Show only if Green selected</option>
    <option class="green" value="green-sel">Show only if Green selected</option>
    <option class="green" value="green-sel">Show only if Green selected</option>
    <option class="blue" value="blue-sel">Show only if Blue selected</option>
    <option class="blue" value="blue-sel">Show only if Blue selected</option>
    <option class="blue" value="blue-sel">Show only if Blue selected</option>
    <option class="red" value="red-sel">Show only if Red selected</option>
    <option class="red" value="red-sel">Show only if Red selected</option>
    <option class="red" value="red-sel">Show only if Red selected</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I put the css into my .css file. I copied and pasted the jQuery function into my .js file at the bottom exactly as it is, and when I load the page the jQuery doesn't seem to be working at all.

```
var everything = $('#everything').clone(true);

$('#refine').change(function () {

var selectColour = $('option:selected', this).val().replace(/ /g, "-");

if (refine != 0) {

    var everythingRefined = everything.clone(true).find('.default,.'+selectColour);

    $('#everything').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#everything').empty().append(everythingRefined);

} else {

    $('#everything').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

}

});
```

I'm wondering if I didn't put the jQuery into my .js file correctly. The .js file already had some javascripts, and the .js file is included in the HTML file. It should be working, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just Wrap your JS Code in 

`$(document).ready(function(){


});`

Comment: Like this? `$(document).ready(function(){
  var everything = $('#everything').clone(true);

  $('#refine').change(function () {
      
      var selectColour = $('option:selected', this).val().replace(/ /g, "-");
      
      if (refine != 0) {
          
          var everythingRefined = everything.clone(true).find('.default,.'+selectColour);
          
          $('#everything').removeAttr('disabled');
          $('#everything').empty().append(everythingRefined);
      
      } else {
          
          $('#everything').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          
      }
      
  });
});`

Comment: Ew, terrible formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many A times Fiddle Doesn't Provide The details like:

You've to wrap your JQuery Code In :

`$(document).ready(function(){ // all Jquery Code. });`

But for this

You need to import jquery from its CDN as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

And then Your JS code as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//all Your JS+Jquery.
});
</script>
```

So In Your case : It is Like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var everything = $('#everything').clone(true);
$('#refine').change(function () {
var selectColour = $('option:selected', this).val().replace(/ /g, "-");
if (refine != 0) {    
    var everythingRefined = everything.clone(true).find('.default,.'+selectColour);
    $('#everything').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#everything').empty().append(everythingRefined);
} else {    
    $('#everything').attr('disabled', 'disabled');    
}    
});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
form {
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select id="refine">
    <option class="default" value="0">Please refine...</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
<select id="everything" disabled="disabled">
    <option class="default" value="">Please select</option>
    <option class="green" value="green-sel">Show only if Green selected</option>
    <option class="green" value="green-sel">Show only if Green selected</option>
    <option class="green" value="green-sel">Show only if Green selected</option>
    <option class="blue" value="blue-sel">Show only if Blue selected</option>
    <option class="blue" value="blue-sel">Show only if Blue selected</option>
    <option class="blue" value="blue-sel">Show only if Blue selected</option>
    <option class="red" value="red-sel">Show only if Red selected</option>
    <option class="red" value="red-sel">Show only if Red selected</option>
    <option class="red" value="red-sel">Show only if Red selected</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**--EDIT--**

According To your Comment:

To Keep Your JS in another File:
Create a File `myjs.js` (You can give any name)
Keep your all JS code in that file.
and then USE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/myjs.js"></script>
```

snippet of contents of myjs.js in this case:
file: `myjs.js`:

```
var everything; //note change 2
function changer(x){//note change
var selectColour = $('option:selected', x).val().replace(/ /g, "-"); //note change
if (refine != 0) {    
var everythingRefined = everything.clone(true).find('.default,.'+selectColour);
$('#everything').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#everything').empty().append(everythingRefined);
} else {    
$('#everything').attr('disabled', 'disabled');    
}    
}
```

And Change Your HTML as:
file `filename.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/myjs.js"></script><!-- Note: Change -->
<style type="text/css">
form {
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body OnLoad="everything = $('#everything').clone(true);"><!-- Note:change 2-->
<form>
<select id="refine" onChange="changer(this);"> <!-- Note Change -->
    <option class="default" value="0">Please refine...</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
<select id="everything" disabled="disabled">
    <option class="default" value="">Please select</option>
    <option class="green" value="green-sel">Show only if Green selected</option>
    <option class="green" value="green-sel">Show only if Green selected</option>
    <option class="green" value="green-sel">Show only if Green selected</option>
    <option class="blue" value="blue-sel">Show only if Blue selected</option>
    <option class="blue" value="blue-sel">Show only if Blue selected</option>
    <option class="blue" value="blue-sel">Show only if Blue selected</option>
    <option class="red" value="red-sel">Show only if Red selected</option>
    <option class="red" value="red-sel">Show only if Red selected</option>
    <option class="red" value="red-sel">Show only if Red selected</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope It'll Help you!! Cheers !

Comment: This worked perfect, I didn't know I had to import jQuery from is CDN or wrap it, thank you. Is there a way I can keep all the javascript in the seperate .js file then import it and make it work that way?

Comment: The edit works as for how I want to set up the files, but making the change to the javascript seemed to create a bug when you change the first box to a different color, then the second box to one of the selections, then changing the first box again. The second box stops displaying the options.

Comment: Look at lines commented at end like: Note Change 2

Comment: That last edit is exactly what I needed. Now I can use this example to accomplish what I really wanted.Thanks for all the timely replies +1

Comment: I am Glad That I Could Help you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to keep this line

```
var everything = $('#everything').clone(true);
```

inside of change method. Just check if everything  is defined inside of change function by doing console.log(everything) inside of change function.

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score -1):

did you forget to include "jQuery"?

> ```
> http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
> ```